# Understanding cost of multiple . and -> operator use?

Tags: c++, optimization

Out of habit, when accessing values via . or ->, I assign them to variables anytime the value is going to be used more than once. My understanding is that in scripting languages like actionscript, this is pretty important. However, in C/C++, I'm wondering if this is a meaningless chore; am I wasting effort that the compiler is going to handle for me, or am I exercising a good practice, and why?

```
 public struct Foo
    {
        public:
        Foo(int val){m_intVal = val;)
        int GetInt(){return m_intVal;}

        int m_intVal; // not private for sake of last example
    };
    public void Bar()
    {
        Foo* foo = GetFooFromSomewhere();
        SomeFuncUsingIntValA(foo->GetInt()); // accessing via dereference then function
        SomeFuncUsingIntValB(foo->GetInt()); // accessing via dereference then function
        SomeFuncUsingIntValC(foo->GetInt()); // accessing via dereference then function

        // Is this better?
        int val = foo->GetInt();
        SomeFuncUsingIntValA(val);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValB(val);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValC(val);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        // And likewise with . operator
        Foo fooDot(5);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValA(fooDot.GetInt()); // accessing via function
        SomeFuncUsingIntValB(fooDot.GetInt()); // accessing via function
        SomeFuncUsingIntValC(fooDot.GetInt()); // accessing via function

        // Is this better?
        int valDot = foo.GetInt();
        SomeFuncUsingIntValA(valDot);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValB(valDot);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValC(valDot);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        // And lastly, a dot operator to a member, not a function
        SomeFuncUsingIntValA(fooDot.m_intVal); // accessing via member
        SomeFuncUsingIntValB(fooDot.m_intVal); // accessing via member
        SomeFuncUsingIntValC(fooDot.m_intVal); // accessing via member

        // Is this better?
        int valAsMember = foo.m_intVal;
        SomeFuncUsingIntValA(valAsMember);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValB(valAsMember);
        SomeFuncUsingIntValC(valAsMember);
    }
```

Comment: are you working on a program where 100ms makes the difference between an unusable application and a working one? If not, your question is pointless. If yes, you need to **profile**, which again renders your question moot. Don’t know if I made myself understood, but there are so many question about premature micro–optimizations I don’t have the will to make an extended point.

Comment: guess I found the will.

Comment: Objects in C++ are not hash tables like they are in ActionScript and whatnot.  The compiler just lays the object out in memory as you specify it.  So field access is as simple as offsetting a pointer and then chasing it---no hash table operations are necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I try to go for an answer here.

Short version: you definitely don’t need to to this.

Long version: you might need to do this.

So here it goes: in interpreted programs like `Javascript` theese kind of things might have a noticeable impact. In compiled programs, like C++, not so much to the point of not at all.

Most of the times you don’t need to worry with these things because an immense amount of resources have been pulled into compiler optimization algorithms (and actual implementations) that the compiler will correctly decide what to do: allocate an extra register and save the result in order to reuse it or recompute every time and save that register space, etc.

There are instances where the compiler can’t do this. That is when it can’t prove multiple calls produce the same result. Then it has no choice but to make all the calls.

Now let’s assume that the compiler makes the wrong choice and you as a precaution make the effort of micro–optimizations. You make the optimization and you squish a 10% performance increase (which is already an overly overly optimistic figure for this kind of optimization) on that portion of code. But what do you know, your code spends only 1% of his time in that portion of code. The rest of the time is most likely spend in some hot loops and waiting for data fetch. So you spend a non-negligible amount of effort to optimize yourself the code only to get a 0.1% performance increase in total time, which won’t even be observable due to the external factors that vary the execution time by way more than that amount.

So don’t spend time with micro-optimizations in C++.

However there are cases where you might need to do this and even crazier things. But this is only after properly **profiling** your code and this is another discussion.

So worry about readability, don’t worry about micro–optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not really related to `->` and `.` operators, but rather about repetitive expressions in general. Yes, it is true that most modern compilers are smart enough to optimize the code that evaluates the same expression repeatedly (assuming it has no observable side-effects).

However, using an explicit intermediate variable typically makes the program much more readable, since it explicitly exposes the fact that the same value is supposed to be used in all contexts. It exposes the fact the it was *your intent* to use the same value in all contexts.

If you repeat using the same expression to generate that value again and again, this fact becomes much less obvious. Firstly, it is difficult to say at the first sight whether the expressions are really identical (especially when they are long). Secondly, it is not obvious whether sequential evaluations of the seemingly the same expression produce identical results.

Finally, slicing long expressions into smaller ones by using intermediate variables can significantly simply debugging the code in step-by-step debugger, since it give the user much greater degree of control through "step in" and "step over" commands.

Answer (score 1):

It's for sure better in terms of readability and maintainability  to have such temporary variable.

In terms of performance, you shouldn't worry about such micro-optimization at this stage (premature optimization). Moreover, modern C++ compilers can optimize it anyway, so you really shouldn't worry about it.